# Changing ylim (axis limits) drops data falling outside range. How can this be prevented?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
df <- data.frame(age=c(10,10,20,20,25,25,25),veg=c(0,1,0,1,1,0,1))
g=ggplot(data=df,aes(x=age,y=veg))
g=g+stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="point")
```

Points reflect mean of veg at each age, which is what I expected and want to preserve after changing axis limits with the command below.

```
g=g+ylim(0.2,1)
```

Changing axis limits with the above command unfortunately causes veg==0 subset to be dropped from the data, yielding

> "Warning message: Removed 4 rows containing missing values (stat_summary)"

This is bad because now the data plot (stat_summary mean) omits the veg==0 points. How can this be prevented? I simply want to avoid showing the empty part of the plot- the ordinate from 0 to .2, but not drop the associated data from the stat_summary calculation.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

you can do that by specifying the coord system:

```
df <- data.frame(age=c(10,10,20,20,25,25,25),veg=c(0,1,0,1,1,0,1))
g=ggplot(data=df,aes(x=age,y=veg))
g=g+stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="point")
g+coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0.2,1)) #do not use +ylim() here
```

Comment: This gets everything presented on the same scale, which is good, and avoids dropping the out-of-range values, which is good, but now the y-axis labels only show the range that actually contain values, which I find undesirable.  Not sure how to make the axis reflect the full range of the plot.

Comment: Does someone know why you have to specify coordinate system in order not to drop values? Why not to have this as a default setting? The example here is probably not the best one, but if you have large error bars for a couple of values, and want to limit the range of y-axis to a show general pattern, this solution works perfectly. If I use ylim() or scale_y_continuous() the error bars going over the range are not drawn at all.